# Merging a branch

Tags: git

I created a new branch to do my own work on:

```
git checkout -b new_changes
```

made changes, and then did

```
git commit -a -m "redesigned flow"
```

All my changes were shown. When I want to push the new branch, I do

```
git push -u origin new_changes
```

However, I get  the following message:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/account/repo.git/' not found
```

My initial thought was that I don't have permissions, but after telling my boss (who owns the repository) he says that I need to create a pull request. However, to my understanding, as there is only one branch (master), I can't do that, since I don't have my own branch pushed. Am I missing something, or is he?

Comment: You need to be able to push before you can create the pull request. Most likely the repository is private and you don't have access. Github will then give you a "not found" error message so as not to leak project or product names to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can contribute to somebody else's GitHub repository through a Pull Request:

1. Fork the original repository. There's a button for that on GitHub, when you visit the page of a repository.
2. Add your fork as a remote in your local work tree
3. Push to your fork
4. Visit your fork on GitHub. There will be a button to create a Pull Request to the original repository (of your boss)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you get written permissions on that repo (unlikely under normal circumstances) what you should do is create a repo of your own on github and create a pull request so that your boss can pull it into his repo.